# Can I rewrite this double loop with condition better (shorter) using array methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Can I rewrite this double loop with a condition and a method call inside in a better way (shorter) using array methods in Javascript?

```
listA.forEach(a => {
    listB.forEach(b => {
        if (a.name === b.name) {
            a.doSomething(b);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No, that's basically as short as it gets.

Comment: What does `doSomething` do? If you are trying to do data manipulation a `map` or `reduce` might be better than a `forEach` but that depends on the what you are doing.

Comment: Idk how you feel about Lodash but it has a `unionBy` function https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#unionBy. You could do a `forEach` over the resulting array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's no where shorter but maybe more readable and it's more a stream-way of doing javascript without having all those nested loops:

```
listA
.filter(a => listB.map(b => b.name).includes(a.name))
.forEach(a => {
    console.log(a) // do your stuff here :)
})
```

Comment: I like how this reads and was using array functions as I was looking for but each array method makes the engine loop, right? So it will make the engine loop one more time compared to the original?

Comment: It's way more inefficient (4 loops are being iterated) than yours on a big scale, but in my opinion you always have to decide between readability/maintainability of your code and the efficiency as it a crucial fact in the further development.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's better, but you can do something like this:

```
listA
    .map(a => listB.map(b => ({ a, b }))) // Create Pairs of { a, b } 
    .reduce((r, a) => a.concat(r)) // flatten { a, b }[][] to { a, b }[]
    .filter(o => o.a == o.b) // filter the list 
    .forEach(o => o.a.doSomething(o.b)); // call the function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `if` statement to:

```
a.name === b.name && a.doSomething(b);
```

Idk if that's the kind of better/shorter you are looking for. It uses [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).